# Loop through object and print in pairs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an object `video` for the view of my node.js app which contains the following.

```
{ title: 
       [ 'Jason Fried: Why work doesn\'t happen at work',
         'John Maeda: How art, technology and design inform creative leaders',
         'From Storytelling to Storylistening: John Maeda (Future of StoryTelling 2014)' ],
      url: 
       [ 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5XD2kNopsUs&feature=youtu.be',
         'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WAuDCOl9qrk&feature=youtu.be',
         'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U8-Q70gV2Yk&feature=youtu.be' ] }
```

This is the loop

```
<% for (var key in video) { %>
 <li><%= video[key] %></li>
<% } %>
```

And this gives me this

```
<li>title[0] title[1] title[2]</li>
<li>url[0] url[1] url[2]</li>
```

How can I make it so it prints in the following way?

```
<li>title[0] url[0]</li>
<li>title[1] url[1]</li>
<li>title[2] url[2]</li>
```

Comment: looks like your object is like this `{title1:'',title2:'',url1:'',url2:''}`. it should be like `{{title1:'',url1:''},{title2:'',url2:''}}` so that you can loop it correctly for each object and get title and url.

Comment: What about `<% for (var i = 0; i < video.title.length; i++) { %> 
<li><%=video.title[i]%> <%=video.url[i]%> <%}%>` ?

Comment: @DragonRock That worked for me. I'm happy to accept it if you make it as an answer.

Comment: @JSantosh Can you please give me heads up on creating array in that structure? Mine is `var video = {},
   titles = [],
   urls = []

  Object.keys(data.list).forEach(function(item) {
   titles.push(data.list[item].resolved_title);
   urls.push(data.list[item].resolved_url);
  })

  video.title = titles;
  video.url = urls;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the structure of your object, and assuming you have as many url as videos, you should do something like this :

```
<% for (var i = 0; i < video.title.length; i++) { %> 
    <li><%=video.title[i]%> <%=video.url[i]%></li>
<% } %>
```

**EDIT**

If you want to use the loop you are currently trying, you should build your object like this :

```
// Video will be a list of objects
var video = [];

Object.keys(data.list).forEach(function(item) {
    video.push({
        title : data.list[item].resolved_title,
        url : data.list[item].resolved_url
    )};
})
```

Then, you'll be able to write your loop like this :

```
<% for (var key in video) { %>
     <li><%= video[key].title %> <%=video[key].url%></li>
<% } %>
```

Comment: Would you mind telling me how I can build an array in this structure?{{title1:'',url1:''},{title2:'',url2:''}  I currently have `var video = {},
   titles = [],
   urls = []

  Object.keys(data.list).forEach(function(item) {
   titles.push(data.list[item].resolved_title);
   urls.push(data.list[item].resolved_url);
  })

  video.title = titles;
  video.url = urls;`